# Linear Code (9,5): Is my Parity Check correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, coding-theory, binary

I have an exercise about designing parity checks for the Hamming (9,5) group code with minimum distance $3$. I use the following notation for the generator matrix:
$$
G=\begin{bmatrix}I&P\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that $I$ is the identity $5\times 5$ matrix and $P$ is a $5\times 4$ matrix doing the parity checks. Now to my analysis and solution:

---

If $u,v\in\mathbb B^5$ have $d(u,v)=1$ we must have $d(uP,vP)\geq 2$ in order to have $d(uG,vG)\geq 3$. Now $d(u,v)=1$ iff. $u=v+e_i$ so it follows that $d(uP,vP)=wt(e_i P)\geq 2$ which shows that each row of $P$ must have weight at least 2.

If $d(u,v)=2$ we must have $u=v+e_i+e_j,i\neq j$ and $d(uP,vP)=wt(e_i P-e_j P)\geq 1$. This means that $e_i P$ and $e_j P$ has to be different, so this only implies that $P$ must have all rows different.

---

If I am correct thus far, I have found one solution to be
$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

So does my analysis make sense and is my solution valid?

**NOTE:** Please beware that this area is very new to me so keep it close to the level of difficulty I presented here, and I would be very grateful for that!

Comment: The logic and the solution both look very good to me. I guess I want to make a few remarks. Sometimes minimum distance $d$ is expressed in the (equivalent) form: no $d-1$ columns of the check matrix should be linearly dependent. Here the check matrix has the form $H=(P^T|I_4)$, and your conditions tell us exactly that any pair of column of $H$ is linearly independent.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you very much! That makes sense and it moves me one step forward towards getting the hang of it! You were the first to help me when I started here on mathSE, and I appreciate so much that a so higly qualified person takes the time to consider my humble problems!

Comment: The other remark is that according to many a source the (binary) Hamming codes have parameters $n=2^m-1$, $k=2^m-1-m$, $d=3$. Your code is one of the codes we get by shortening the $(15,11)$ Hamming code in six positions. I guess it is a matter of taste, whether we still want to call it a Hamming code. Suit yourself! I have also seen the term *group code* mean a code (in possibly a very different space such as Euclidean and/or a manifold) that is a single orbit of a finite a group of isometries. Here I would prefer the term *linear code*, but whatever :-)

Comment: Typo: Should read *pair of columns of $H$* (i.e. plural) towards the end of my 1st comment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yes, I thought too that coding (9,5) made little sense just like (6,3) seems an inefficient use of 3 parity checks since you can get (7,4) instead.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: *Typos* are most appreciated ;) I am not a native speaker, so it takes some of the pressure of me that others make *typos*!

Comment: Well, sometimes your boss tells you to design a code, and tells you that there is room for a total of 9 bits! It's nice to know that you can still do something :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I am starting to somewhat like those Hamming codes. But it puzzles me that the concepts of being parallel and orthogonal seem to coincide in $\mathbb B^n$, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Hm ... wrong - they do not quite. If the weight is even, the vector is parallel and orthogonal to itself at the same time ... Still the behaviour is strange :)

Comment: That's what sometimes happens, when the "inner product" is not positive definite as is the case in real vector spaces. The so called [self dual codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_code) are a well researched area of coding theory with a lot of beautiful math and difficult combinatorics going on. Not very hot in terms of applications, but do we really care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution and the logic leading up to it are impeccable. When a binary linear $(n,k)$-code is described in terms of a parity check matrix $H=M_{n-k,n}(\Bbb{F}_2)$ a known design criterion is: the minimum distance is $\ge d$, if no set of $d-1$ columns is linearly dependent.

If the generator matrix of a binary linear code is $G=(I_k|P)$, then the parity check matrix is $H=(P^T|I_{n-k})$. So in your case
$$
H_{\mathrm{String}}=\left(\begin{array}{l}100101000\\110010100\\011100010\\001010001\end{array}\right).
$$
Your conditions amounted to requiring that no two columns of this matrix should be equal, and this is manifestly the case.

Your code is an example of a *shortened Hamming code*. The (binary) Hamming code of length 15 and rank 11 has a check matrix consisting of all the fifteen non-zero binary columns of four bits
$$
H_{\mathrm{Hamming}}=\left(\begin{array}{l}101010101010101\\011001100110011\\
000111100001111\\000000011111111\end{array}\right).
$$
You see that you get your check matrix by removing columns $7,9,11,13,14$ and $15$ from the Hamming check matrix and reordering the columns. The latter operation never affects the minimum distance.

Comment: So if I get this right, the columns of the check matrix for $(2^s-1,2^s-1-s)$ with minimum distance $3$ (i.e. single-error recovery) can be constructed by listing the binary numbers $1,2,...,2^s-1$ and using their digits as entries in column vectors. Since they are all different, they are pairwise linearly independent as desired. This also proves already that this is possible for all $(2^s-1,2^s-1-s)$ codes. So for instance $(1023,1013)$ will work and is easily constructed this way.

Comment: Correct, @String. Hamming was a smart dude.

Comment: Thanks again! Is my elaboration given as an answer correctly understood?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit inconvenient to place as a comment and also as an edit to the original question, so I take the liberty to answer my own question checking that I get the details of [Jyrki Lahtonen's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) (JL) insightful answer correct:

If we apply the strategy presented by JL to the well known Hamming $(7,4)$ code we get
$$
\newcommand{\red}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\gray}{\color{gray}}
H_{(7,4)}=\left(\begin{array}{l}\red1\gray0\blue1\gray0\blue{101}\\\gray0\red1\blue1\gray0\blue{011}\\
\gray{00}\blue0\red1\blue{111}\end{array}\right)
$$
Naturally the identity part of $H$ is placed at columns $1,2,4$. Generally they will be at $1,2,4,...,2^{s-1}$. Thus the parity checks can be found in other positions in each row, namely $3,5,6,7$. Generally they are found in $\{1,2,...,2^s-1\}\setminus\{1,2,4,...,2^{s-1}\}$. So if we were to construct the generator matrix $G$ corrsponding to this, it would be
$$
G=
\begin{pmatrix}
\blue1&\blue1&\gray1&\blue0&\gray0&\gray0&\gray0\\
\blue1&\blue0&\gray0&\blue1&\gray1&\gray0&\gray0\\
\blue0&\blue1&\gray0&\blue1&\gray0&\gray1&\gray0\\
\blue1&\blue1&\gray0&\blue1&\gray0&\gray0&\gray1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the parity checks has been placed at columns $1,2,4$. The remaining columns of $G$ form the identity $I_4$. The order matters, since they have to be placed correctly to match the transposed version of the parity checks in $H$ so that the bit designated for the first row in $G$ ends up being multiplied by the third column in $H$ etc.

---

So in a computer one can easily implement this general description and work with Hamming code $(1023,1013)$ where $H$ is constructed by putting the binary digits of $1,2,...,2^s-1$ in columns and $G$ is constructed by picking out positions that are not powers of $2$ in the $i$-th row of $H$ and placing them in the $2^{i-1}$ column of $G$. If we remove the power-of-$2$-columns from $G$ we are left with a $k\times k$ identity matrix.